# Flutter CustomScrollView did not scroll full length

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have used the cupertinoApp widget for iOS application to achieve the more than a list on single page but somehow my list did not scroll fully Can anyone help to scroll the list?

I have attached the code that i have used

```
  buildHomeDetailsPage(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                (sImageList.length > 0)
                    ? buildTopSliderImages(sImageList)
                    : new Container(),
                (featureProductDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildLatestProductTitle()
                    : new Container(),
                (featureProductDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildLatestProduct()
                    : new Container(),
                (bannerDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Current Offer')
                    : new Container(),
                (bannerDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildBannerOffer(bannerDataList)
                    : new Container(),
                (hotdealDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Hot Deals')
                    : new Container(),
                (hotdealDataList.length > 0)
                    ? buildHotDealProduct()
                    : new Container(),
                SizedBox(height: 12.0),
                (bannerOfferList.length > 0)
                    ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Best Offers')
                    : new Container(),
                (bannerOfferList.length > 0)
                    ? buildOfferBannerProduct()
                    : new Container()
              ],
            ))
      ],
    ));
```

}

and I have used that method on here

```
     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.context = context;

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: buildHomeDetailsPage(context),
    );
  }
```

I have captured video for a better understanding of my issue.
**Video Reference link:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m6fK4PKVFAp81k5-QFIDtLQzwTBibwuk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: SliverList has own scroll feature. So try again without CustomScrollView. Or you can use only CustomScrollView.

Comment: Could you post the code inside the methods like buildTopSliderImages()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have got the answer to as my issue.

Basically, In parent, i have used below code

```
 Positioned(
              top: 90.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex))
```

so that is reason scrollable did not work it. so I have replaced the below code then scroll working fine the same as I expected.not sure what is reason to prevent the scroll only for Cupertino but below code help me to fix the issue on Cupertino.

```
 Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 80.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: _getDrawerItemWidget(_selectedDrawerIndex)),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case try this.

```
return Container(
          child : SingleChildScrollView(
             child Column(
               children : <widget>
          [
            (sImageList.length > 0)
                ? buildTopSliderImages(sImageList)
                : new Container(),
            (featureProductDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildLatestProductTitle()
                : new Container(),
            (featureProductDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildLatestProduct()
                : new Container(),
            (bannerDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Current Offer')
                : new Container(),
            (bannerDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildBannerOffer(bannerDataList)
                : new Container(),
            (hotdealDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Hot Deals')
                : new Container(),
            (hotdealDataList.length > 0)
                ? buildHotDealProduct()
                : new Container(),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0),
            (bannerOfferList.length > 0)
                ? buildCurrentOfferTitle('Best Offers')
                : new Container(),
            (bannerOfferList.length > 0)
                ? buildOfferBannerProduct()
                : new Container()
          ]
             )
          )
)
```

Comment: I have tried this snippet but list is freeze and did not scroll it :(

Comment: It will work. Please share your screenshot or video. I can help you

Comment: Thanks for your support!! Please check this video that shows scroll is freeze
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wA2dfrY3wSiaTf6vHtJVIJbpVu0K0LM4/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hmm... Can you share your product list build widget method? Did you use ListView to build the Product list? As you can, please share your whole code. Your code is not enough to fix issues.

Comment: Okay, Please find the whole dart file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ROVCiDRYzSrt_gYtaiBib4PcImTKn-xo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I found some issues. And I have one question. Do you need whole scroll? Let's discuss at chat room

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200876/discussion-between-akio-alex-and-mbpatel).